# Error in method - using Iterator to interweave a List

Tags: java, list, iterator

I've created a method that should interweave two list objects and return the new, inter-weaved, list.

i.e. If aList is [A,C,E,G] & bList is [B, D, F] the method will return a list containing [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]

There are no compiler errors and when I run the program, the List returned is empty. I've figured out that the program doesn't make it into the for loop because for some reason when I create **newList** it is of size 0.

Here is the code:

```
    public static <E> List<E> interweave(List<E> a, List<E> b){
    List<E> newList = new ArrayList<E>(a.size() + b.size());

    Iterator<E> itrA = a.iterator();
    Iterator<E> itrB = b.iterator();

    for(int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++){
        if(i%2 == 0)
            newList.add(i, itrA.next());
        else
            newList.add(i, itrB.next());
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Comment: the Constructor `new ArrayList(size)` does allocate a new Array with the size that you defined. But the `ArrayList#size` doesn´t return the Length of the Array, it returns a variable `size`, which is changed after manipulating the `List`. After creating the new `ArrayList`, the size is still 0.

Comment: Thanks man! that explained exactly what I needed to know! So when I use  `new ArrayList()` and then in the `for` loop use the value of `a.size() + b.size()` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this can be done in a more simple way, using `while(iterator.hasNext())` idiom:

```
itrA = a.iterator();
itrB = b.iterator(); 

while (itrA.hasNext() || itrB.hasNext()) {
  if (itrA.hasNext())
      newList.add(itrA.next());
  if (itrB.hasNext())
      newList.add(itrB.next());
}
```

Comment: Simple and best solution. +1.

Comment: Thanks man! That is a simpler way to get the job done. Also when I use  `new ArrayList()` and then in the `for` loop use the value of `a.size() + b.size()` it works perfectly.

Comment: plus one for simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to compose the lists dynamically:

```
static class InterWeave<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    // The lists to be interwoven.
    final Iterable<T>[] lists;

    public InterWeave(Iterable<T>... lists) {
        this.lists = lists;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new WeaveIterator();

    }

    private class WeaveIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        // Which list to offer next.
        int whichList = 0;
        // The Iterators of those lists.
        final List<Iterator<T>> iterators = new ArrayList(lists.length);
        // The current iterator.
        Iterator<T> i;
        // The next to deliver - null menas not primed yet.
        T next = null;

        public WeaveIterator() {
            // Take some iterators.
            for (Iterable<T> l : lists) {
                if (l != null) {
                    iterators.add(l.iterator());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // Have we already prepared one?
            if (next == null) {
                // Grab the next iterator and step on.
                i = iterators.get(whichList++);
                // detect that we're back at start.
                Iterator<T> start = i;
                // Cycle around the iterators.
                whichList %= iterators.size();
                while (!i.hasNext()) {
                    // Get next one.
                    i = iterators.get(whichList++);
                    whichList %= iterators.size();
                    if (i == start) {
                        // Stop here if we've gone all the way around.
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i.hasNext()) {
                    next = i.next();
                }
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (hasNext()) {
                T n = next;
                // Mark it used.
                next = null;
                return n;
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }

    }

}

public void test() {
    List<String> a = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "C", "E", "G"});
    List<String> b = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B", "D", "F"});
    for (String s : new InterWeave<String>(a, b)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```